# How do I read JSON as String with Gson?

Tags: android, string, gson, inputstream, logcat

I'm getting a Json from a `WebService` and I want to print it as a `String` in my LogCat. I've tried the following:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
HttpEntity getResponseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = getResponseEntity.getContent();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
Type snsType = new TypeToken<SNSRegister>(){}.getType();
snsRegister = gson.fromJson(reader, snsType);
String jsonString = convertStreamToString(is);
```

`snsRegister` is an instance of my serializable class, i'm trying to print the JSON in my logcat by converting the `InputStream` object to `String` with the `convertStreamtoString` method:

```
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

but my String is always empty and I don't know why. `snsRegister` is not null, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: you are reading twice from the same inputstream. you can't do that. what you can do is read to string first, then log, the call fromJson with the string as param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If this is really important for you to do, `Gson` can take a `String`.

I don't recommend reading the `Stream` twice, though you can do it with `mark()` and `reset()`. Since `Gson` will deserialize a `String` in addition to `Reader`, so you can just pass the `String` into Gson like this:

```
HttpEntity getResponseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = getResponseEntity.getContent();
String jsonString = convertStreamToString(is);
Log.i("MyTAG", jsonString);

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type snsType = new TypeToken<SNSRegister>() {}.getType();
snsRegister = gson.fromJson(jsonString, snsType);
```

I don't recommend doing this in production though, as the conversion to a `String` is a lot of extra work. But you can use this temporarily for debugging, obviously; the way you're currently doing it is the best way for production.

Another option would be to convert the `SNSRegister` object back to JSON with `gson.toJson()`, but that would be even slower.

Comment: @JaviSanchezG Thanks for the checkmark! You got two reputation points for that, too!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your stream has been read once by GSON.

If you really, really want to read it twice you need to `reset()` a stream but first you have to `mark()` the position you want to reset to.

But all you want is to print your JSON in logcat just add `toString()` method to your `SNSRegister` class or even better user `Retrofit` logging mechanism.

Comment: `Some implementations support marking a position in the input stream`, so this may or may not work